# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Uploading Multiple images Nodejs express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, express

I want to upload multiple images and save the details in a mysql database using nodejs and express. I'm able to pass the files to the server side but I am having this error (ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT) as I attempt to move the files in a loop.

This is my code (backend):

```
export const addImages = async(req, res) => {
if(req.files === null) return res.status(400).json({msg: "No File Uploaded"});
const productId = req.params.id;
const userId = req.userId;
const file = req.files.prodImages;
const allowedType = ['.png','.jpg','.jpeg'];
try {
    for(let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        let fileSize = file[i].data.length;
        let ext = path.extname(file[i].name);
        let fileName = file[i].md5 + ext;
        if(!allowedType.includes(ext.toLowerCase())) return res.status(422).json({msg: "Invalid Images"});
        if(fileSize > 5000000) return res.status(422).json({msg: "Image must be less than 5 MB"});
       file[i].mv(`./public/images/${fileName}`, async(err)=>{
            if(err) return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message});
            await Image.create({ 
                name: fileName, 
                productId: productId, 
                userId: userId 
            });
        });
    }
res.status(200).json({msg: "Images Added"});
} catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({msg: error.message});
} }
```

Comment: Kind of hard to follow code with poor indentation.  I'd suggest you edit the question to fix the code indendation.

Answer (score 0):

A problem is that you're mixing asynchronous callbacks `file[i].mv()` with promises  `await Image.create()` and that makes proper error handling and proper control flow very difficult.  Thus, you have multiple ways you may be sending more than one response which is what triggers `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]`.

The easiest solution is usually to use only promise control flow and, in this case that would mean converting the `.mv()` method to use promises.  I don't know what that method is from (you don't show where it comes from).  If it has a promise interface already, you should just use it instead of the plain callback you're using now.  If it doesn't, you should create one by promisifying it.

Without knowing where the `.mv()` interface comes from, here's a generic way to promisify it.  With more specific knowledge of where the interface comes from, there might be a more efficient way to promisify it.

```
import { promisify } from 'node:util';

export const addImages = async (req, res) => {
    if (req.files === null) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: "No File Uploaded" });
    }
    const productId = req.params.id;
    const userId = req.userId;
    const file = req.files.prodImages;
    const allowedType = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'];
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
            let fileSize = file[i].data.length;
            let ext = path.extname(file[i].name);
            let fileName = file[i].md5 + ext;
            if (!allowedType.includes(ext.toLowerCase())) return res.status(422).json({ msg: "Invalid Images" });
            if (fileSize > 5000000) {
                return res.status(422).json({ msg: "Image must be less than 5 MB" });
            }
            file[i].mvPromise = promisify(file[i].mv);
            await file[i].mvPromise(`./public/images/${fileName}`);
            await Image.create({
                name: fileName,
                productId: productId,
                userId: userId
            });
        }
        res.status(200).json({ msg: "Images Added" });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ msg: error.message });
    }
}
```